# The function MkDir in Excel VBA in a macos surounding always returns a runtime error "76": Path not found

Tags: excel, vba, office365

Maybe this is due to the fact that I'm using Excel-VBA for Office 365 on an iMac!

Here is the coding I've been using:

```
 If Len(Dir("Benutzer/Bob/Dokumente/Website-Inhalte/Italy/Tuscany/Photos/" & SeitenText, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
      MkDir "Benutzer/Bob/Dokumente/Website-Inhalte/Italy/Tuscany/Photos/" & SeitenText
 End If
```

I've checked and double checked to be sure that all folders etc. exist.

I'm stumped!!!

Comment: Do you need a forward slash at the start? (i.e. "/Benutzer/Bob/Dokumente/Website-Inhalte/Italy/Tuscany/Photos/")

Comment: Maybe your current directory is not what you expect?  Assuming that's a thing on Mac...